How to check how much space is free in the current working directory?
How to check how much space is free in the current working directory on a Linux system?
I have a filesize file which contains 1073741824 which is the amount of disk space in bytes that is needed.
I need something to check in a script that in the folder are contents-of-filesize * 1,25 bytes free.  How to do that?
pwd can print the path of the current folder, but how to combine that with df?

With GNU df:
if
  df --output=avail --block-size=1 . | awk '
    BEGIN {getline size < "filesize"; size *= 1.25}
    NR == 2 {exit !($0 >= size)}'
then
  echo 'There is enough available disk space in the file system the current working directory is in.'
fi

. is always a path to the current working directory, while the output of pwd (which often just prints the contents of $PWD and depending on the shell, without always checking it still represents a path to the current working directory) is not always¹.
df's avail column is the amount of space available to regular users. That may be less than the space available to the superuser as there's often a percentage of the disk space reserved for root for emergency recovery when the filesystem gets full.
To get the free space, some of which may not be available to you, you can compute size - used instead:
if
  df --output=size,used --block-size=1 . | awk '
    BEGIN {getline size < "filesize"; size *= 1.25}
    NR == 2 {exit !($1 - $2 >= size)}'
then
  echo 'There is enough disk space but I might not be able to use it.'
fi


¹ It's also cumbersome to retrieve its output reliably when the path² of the currently working directory may end in newline characters. You might as well use $PWD directly.
² Well pwd prints a path to the current working directory, usually the one derived from the directories you called cd with to get there. Of the potentially many possible paths that lead to the current working directory, that is not necessary the canonical one for which you need pwd -P instead, not that it would make a different when that path is passed to df.

how to use it instead of 1073741824 , in howmuchsizeisneed.txt in there is the value.
"$(cat howmuchsizeisneed.txt)" does not work.

@user447274, see edit.

i do not understand it, and it does not work for me here. i know now two thinks,
if du -b in/ | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'  *  1,25
(dont know how to calculate the "*1,25" smaler than df --block-size=1 . | awk '{print$4}' | tail -n 1 it is ok, go on in the script, but if not, exit the script. but how to insert this into a bash script? (the way with awk directly must be better, but it does not work here and i do not understand it.
